# How to derive JSON data from the DOM structure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
<form id="foo-bar-baz-form">
    <input name="bar.baz" value="">
    <input name="baz" value="">
    <input name="foo.bar.baz" value="">
</form>
```

I need to write a function to derive the JSON data like below

```
 {
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": ""
        }
    },
    "bar": {
        "baz": ""
    },
    "baz": ""
 }
```

I need to write a function which accepts id of the dom as input and returns the JSON as output.

```
function getJSON(id){

   return JSON;
}

I had idea like this

1) loop through children nodes
2) get the name of each children node
3) split the name into array
4) If the array item is not last item, add an object and add the array item as key
```

How can I derive this JSON from the above DOM in efficient way ?

Comment: I don't see how to the output relates to the input.  I get lost on "foo.baz" generating `"bar": { "baz": "" }` and "foo.bar.baz" generating just `"baz": ""`

Comment: It's useful to know that a DOM element is an object with properties like `children`, `name` and `value`.  See the link, maybe make an attempt knowing that, and edit the question.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: @danh Sorry I modified the input. Can you please check now..

Comment: @Teemu I have modified the input. Can you please check now.

Comment: Ok I'll add the code what I've tried @Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is just a bit more complex than the idea you've introduced. When creating branches from the "properties" in the form element names, you will need a recursive function to follow the "path" before the value of the last property can be set. Something like this:

```js
function form2Obj(form) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(form) !== '[object HTMLFormElement]') {
    return;
  }
  const obj = Object.create(null); // The return value
  const inputs = Array.from(form.elements);
  // Creates new properties and values to the return value object
  const addProp = (target, name, element) => {
    const branches = name.split('.');
    // Extract the current name to handle
    const current = branches.shift();
    if (branches.length) {
      // Not the last part of the name
      if (!(current in target)) {
        // The property doens't exist, create it
        target[current] = {};
      }
      // Evaluate the next part of the name
      addProp(target[current], branches.join('.'), element);
    } else {
      // This is the last part of the name, get the value from the element
      target[current] = element.value;
    }
  };
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    addProp(obj, input.name, input);
  });
  return obj;
}

console.log(form2Obj(document.querySelector('#foo-bar-baz-form')));
```

```html
<form id="foo-bar-baz-form">
  <input name="bar.baz" value="">
  <input name="baz" value="">
  <input name="foo.bar.baz" value="">
</form>
```

Notice, that `form2Obj` returns an object, you've yet to stringify it to JSON, if JSON is actually needed. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74e9z0gc/) for testing.